# Problems with htaccess and urls of images hosted on my server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

I have the following htaccess to make my urls friendly site

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /miblog/
RewriteRule entry/(.*)$ notice.php?id=$1
```

Thus, if I write entry / news appears id_notice me up there all right.

The problem that the pictures show, the path you choose is of the form: 
entry / url_imagen

And the entry folder does not exist on my server ... is made only to create friendly urls, but there do not want pictures look ...

How do I get my pictures loaded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Prepend two conditions:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /miblog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule entry/(.*)$ notice.php?id=$1
```

The first RewriteCond checks if you are not requesting a file that exists, the second one checks that you are not looking for an existent directory.

So if the url you are requesting point to a regular file it will skip the following RewriteRule.

Comment: Thanks for responding. 

But it does not work, the route that is looking like this: 
http://dominio.es/miblog/entry/uploads/img1.jpg 

And the correct path (which should look) is: 
http://dominio.es/miblog/uploads/img1.jpg 


Any suggestions?

Comment: If you remove the .htaccess the images are correctly shown?

Comment: Yes...But i don´t know why

Comment: It's quite strange because the RewriteRule is rewriting from "entry" to something else and not the reverse. 
So:

- you have another piece of .htaccess OR
- you are rewriting in PHP OR
- the links to the images are relative and not absolute (e.g. src="uploads/img1.jpg"

Comment: Uhmm, and there is no way that the browser does not interpret the url with the "entry /"? 

I thought that you put that htaccess url only visually, but actually working with the notice.php? Id = 

I do not like having to change everything to absolute paths.

Comment: Actually you can use BASE tag in HEAD section to specify "an absolute URI that acts as the base URI for resolving relative URIs": http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE

Comment: Oh, now it works well if I put the BASE path !!! Thanks so much!

But there is still another error (sorry for being so pushy). Now the images are read correctly because the route well BUT, the user session will not work ... the session_start () in php, if I put the BASE tag in the <head> ???

Comment: I think that this should be asked into another question because it is not related to your first question.